# Nested expansion of dataframe which references other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe df0 that looks like this:

```
col 1 | col 2|
  x   | df1  |
  y   | df2  |
```

df1 looks like this:

```
col 3 | col 4
 a    |   b
 c    |   d
```

df2 looks like this:

```
col 3 | col 4
 e    |   f
 g    |   h
```

I would like to expand the dataframe `col2` to get this:

```
col 1 | col 3| col 4
  x   | a    |   b
  x   | c    |   d
  y   | e    |   f
  y   | g    |   h
```

Comment: @smci Left join on what column? Notice col 2 is a list of dataFrame variable names.

Comment: @coldspeed: yes you're right. But You concatenate df1 and df2, then do a funky merge df0['col1'] to the result of those, except that `col2` specifies which sub-dataframe.

Comment: 4 upvotes on question and not one convinced with the answer? Upvoters, concat with keys is the way to go here. Take a look and convince yourself that anything less than this is not going to be generic enough.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! You can upvote my answer if it was helpful as well (click on the triangle above the "0" to the left of my answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible assuming you have a dictionary of DataFrames, and then use `pd.concat` with a little housekeeping:

```
df_dict = {'df1' : df1, 'df2' : df2, ...}
pd.concat(
      [df_dict[d] for d in df['col 2']], keys=df['col 1']
   ).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

```
  col 1 col 3 col 4
0     x     a     b
1     x     c     d
2     y     e     f
3     y     g     h
```